# Is there any alternative to cryopreserve cell lines without -80 freezer?

Tags: cell-culture, cell

My university's -80 freezer just broke down and the repair will take 4 months according to the vendor. Is there any other way to preserve cells? Maintaining lot of flasks until the freezer is repaired is not viable option.

Is there any alternative to cryopreserve cell lines without -80 freezer?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tank of liquid nitrogen is not just an alternative, but a much better substitute, IMHO. The problem of gradually cooling inside a isopropanol container can be overcome by using a box full of dry ice (-79°C as I recall).